# Physics game with cocos2d for iphone v3.0.0

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, game-physics

I'm new to cocos2d-iphone, I'm creating demo app about physics with cocos2d-iphone

I want to create an outline of the basic physics node (**node #1**), to keep some node "in door"

And I add some node (**nodes #2**) into node #1

[image]

But when I rotate node #1, all nodes #2 **fall down**. I can not keep them inside node #1.

I'm using Cocos2D-iPhone version 3.0.0

My demo is here : https://github.com/ditimtriky/DemoCocos2d

Can you help me to fix it?

==================

You can take a quick look at here https://plus.google.com/photos/105576008720153830534/albums/6020993675161389681/6020993675419257554

or

https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-F3WIN7j8_nE/U47d2OI9CtI/AAAAAAAAGVI/eAzccfAPZds/w180-h240-no/1401870652451id172912.gif

=================

```
#import "MyScene.h"

@implementation MyScene {
    CCPhysicsNode *_physicsNode;
}

+ (instancetype)scene {
    return [[self alloc] init];
}

- (void)onEnter {
    [super onEnter];
    glClearColor(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0);

    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"newton.plist"];

    _physicsNode = [CCPhysicsNode node];
    _physicsNode.gravity = ccp(0, 3*-980.665);
    _physicsNode.debugDraw = YES;
    [self addChild:_physicsNode];

    // create an outline of the basic physics node, to keep physics "in door"
    CCNode *outline = [CCNode node];
    outline.contentSize = CGSizeMake(280, 300);
    outline.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5, 0.5);
    outline.position = ccp(160, 284);

    outline.physicsBody = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithPolylineFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 300) cornerRadius:3];
    outline.physicsBody.friction = 1.f;
    outline.physicsBody.elasticity = 0.5f;
    outline.physicsBody.collisionCategories = @[@"outline"];
    outline.physicsBody.collisionMask = @[@"sphere", @"rope"];
    [_physicsNode addChild:outline];

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"letter.o.png"];
        sprite.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5,0.5);
        sprite.position = ccp(160, 284);

        CCPhysicsBody *body =
        [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:25
                                    andCenter:ccp(sprite.contentSize.width/2,sprite.contentSize.height/2)];
        sprite.physicsBody = body;

        body.friction = 0.5;
        body.elasticity = 1.0;
        body.collisionCategories = @[@"sphere"];
        body.collisionMask = @[@"sphere", @"outline"];

        [_physicsNode addChild:sprite];
    }

    //rotate
    [outline runAction:
     [CCActionRepeatForever actionWithAction:
      [CCActionSequence actionWithArray:@[[CCActionRotateTo actionWithDuration:1 angle:180],
                                          [CCActionRotateTo actionWithDuration:1 angle:360]]]]];

    // add a reset button
    CCButton *resetButton = [CCButton buttonWithTitle:@"" spriteFrame:[CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"reset.png"]];
    resetButton.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
    resetButton.position = (CGPoint){0.90f, 0.80f};;
    [resetButton setTarget:self selector:@selector(onResetClicked:)];
    [self addChild:resetButton];
}

- (void)onResetClicked:(id)sender
{
    // recreate the scene
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[self.class scene]];
}

@end
```

Comment: I'm running this again and again, wondering why last node not going out side!, and also i don't find @"rope" anywhere!

Comment: My demo is base on demo Cocos2dNewton of cocos2d v3.0.0. If anything is wrong please explain it for me. Thank you @BaSha

Comment: FYI : try to debug by adding [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setAnimationInterval:30.0/60]; in onEnter of MyScene to analyse behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is mixing actions and physics together in 3.0. The action only sets the position, causing the physics body to "teleport" along with it. This is fixed in 3.1 for static bodies with actions.

If you want to stay on 3.0 you need to update the body's angle and angular velocity manually.

Comment: Yes. I heard someone said that. I will check it now

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible issues:

1. If you're using v3.0, then you shouldn't mix actions (e.g. `CCActionRotateTo`) and physics. Instead of action just apply force, impulse or set angular velocity.
2. Your bounds are too thin. Contained bodies just fall through them. Try representing bounds using 4 rectangles.

Hope this helps.

**Update (answer to comment):**

First of all you need to rotate your outline body in the `fixedUpdate:` method, not in the `update:`.

However, most probably the issue is that the bounds are too thin.

Try creating our container like this:

```
//Thickness of bounds
float thickness = 30.0f;

//Bounds shapes using rects
CCPhysicsShape *bottom = [CCPhysicsShape rectShape:CGRectMake(0,0,280,thickness) cornerRadius:0];
CCPhysicsShape *right = [CCPhysicsShape rectShape:CGRectMake(280-thickness,0,thickness,300) cornerRadius:0];
CCPhysicsShape *top = [CCPhysicsShape rectShape:CGRectMake(0, 300-thickness, 280, thickness) cornerRadius:0];
CCPhysicsShape *left = [CCPhysicsShape rectShape:CGRectMake(0, 0, thickness, 300) cornerRadius:0];    

//Creating body using shapes
outline.physicsBody = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithShapes:@[bottom, left, right, top]];

//Body is static
outline.physicsBody.type = CCPhysicsBodyTypeStatic;

//..rest of your code..
```

Comment: Thanks. I removed rotate action. And I set outine.rotate in `update:` method but nothing changed :(

Comment: Thank you! But when I rotate node#1 too faster, some node#2 went to outside. And I want to make a square with thin border. But I don't know how to make sure all nodes#2 never fall down :(

Comment: I think you won't be able to achieve this with a thin border. If the contained node is pushing outside too hard it will go through, this is what happens when you rotate container too fast even with this thick border. You don't have to make the border visible and you can set its properties so that it only collided with contained balls and not some other stuff on your level.